# Support included directory in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, dynamic-library

I have project in CLion constructed from 2 major parts(2 projects). One is dynamic library(/engine) and the second one is executable(/gui)

My project structure is:
[image]

CMakes looks like this:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

add_subdirectory(engine)
add_subdirectory(gui)
```

/engine/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(enginelib SHARED library.cpp library.h)
```

/gui/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(../engine)
add_executable(gui main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(gui PRIVATE enginelib)
```

Project builds correctly, gui is using engine and it works.
However Clion underscores including from engine and doesn't show things from engine.
[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks for help :)

Btw, It's my first time setting project like this, am I including the engine into gui correctly? Or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: In /engine/CMakeLists.txt add:
target_include_directories(enginelib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

Comment: Normally, enclosing the header with **double quotes** is used only headers in the **current directory**: `#include "library.h"`. For headers from other directories **angle braces** are used: `#include <library.h>`.

Comment: And please do not use include_directories() it's an obsolete style. It's preferable to use targets and properties (target_link_libraries, target_include_directories, target_compile_features etc..)

Comment: @Equod that is what I don't like about CMake. it has several paths to do sth and because I've never focused on CMake, I don't know what is 'the right way' to do sth.

Thanks for help :)